# ERROR: LoadError: PyError ($(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\PyCall\BD546\src\pyfncall.jl:43 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call)

Tags: excel, plot, julia

i was tring to make some plots with .xlsx file ,and
getting the following Error for PyCall and am on JuliaPro_v1.5.4-1

````
```LoadError: PyError ($(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\PyCall\BD546\src\pyfncall.jl:43 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, pyargsptr, kw))))) <class 'xlrd.biffh.XLRDError'>
````

XLRDError('Excel xlsx file; not supported')
File "C:\Users\user.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\xlrd_*init*_.py", line 170, in open_workbook
raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')

Stacktrace:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Img.png) pyerr_check at C:\Users\user.julia\packages\PyCall\BD546\src\exception.jl:62 [inlined]
[2] pyerr_check at C:\Users\user.julia\packages\PyCall\BD546\src\exception.jl:66 [inlined]
[3] _handle_error(::String) at C:\Users\user.julia\packages\PyCall\BD546\src\exception.jl:83
in expression starting at C:\Users\user\Desktop\RN.jl:6 ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Img.png)